# How to use 'relativize' in dnspython but prevent replacing full names with '@'?

Tags: python, dnspython

I am using the [dnspython](https://www.dnspython.org/) package. While processing a file and passing `relativize=False` in `dnspython`'s `from_file()` function, each name of a record is displayed fully, (e.g. 'smtp.example.com.')

I prefer an overview which shows only "smtp" in case of that subdomain. This could be realized by using `relativize=True` in the `from_file()` function. However, in that case, all full DNS names ('example.com') are replaced by an `@` (at symbol).

Can I configure dnspython to relativize subdomains, but show the full DNS name without only showing the `@`?

Comment: How about parsing the results and removing the @? What type are the returned records?

Comment: A dirty workaround would be to do an inplace replacement of the lines in the zonefile with `re.sub(r'^@', domain_name, line)`. I'd prefer to use a supported/official way of dnspython to do this in my application. 
This issue affects all the records of the zone, unrelated to the type of record, if the domain matches the dns name exactly, the notation of dnspython changes to '@' instead of the domain name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Symbol `@` is used by DNS data format. See [RFC1035](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1035.txt) paragraph 5.1:

> A free standing @ is used to denote the current origin.

So it is standard to use `@` for current zone name. You can replace `@` with zone (domain) name if it is needed. Though it is strange to mix relative and full domain names.